# Unit Testing: Can't figure this out?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I'm doing a unit test in my design class, and the shell of the project was given to us. There is only one method in the unit test where I have to add code. I can't change anything else in the code.

I have tried everything I could think of using what C++ knowledge I have and tried Googling different ways to solve this problem. Every result that came up was either too complex because I don't have a background with C#, or the information for what I was looking for was not given.

Here is the original code:

```
class Course
{
    public Course(string id, string title, int creditHours, string description, string prerequisiteCourse)
    {
        this.CourseID = id;
        this.CourseTitle = title;
        this.CreditHours = creditHours;
        this.Description = description;
        this.PrerequisiteCourse = prerequisiteCourse;
    }


    public string CourseID;
    public string CourseTitle;
    public int CreditHours;
    public string Description;
    public string PrerequisiteCourse;
}


class CourseListTest
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GetCourseByCourseIDTestWhenCourseExists();
        GetCourseByCourseIDTestWhenCourseDoesNotExist();
    }


    public static void GetCourseByCourseIDTestWhenCourseExists()
    {

        CourseList myCourseList = new CourseList();
        Course myCourse = myCourseList.GetCourseByCourseID("CIS 400");
        if (myCourse.CourseID != "CIS 400")
            System.Console.WriteLine("ERROR - GetCourseByCourseIDTestWhenCourseExists(): Returned CourseID Not equal (CIS 400)");
    }

    public static void GetCourseByCourseIDTestWhenCourseDoesNotExist()
    {

        CourseList myCourseList = new CourseList();
        Course myCourse = myCourseList.GetCourseByCourseID("CIS 101");
        if (myCourse != null)
            System.Console.WriteLine("ERROR - GetCourseByCourseIDTestWhenCourseDoesNotExist(): should have returned null");
    }
}
```

Here is were the problem lies in the next class. We are to enter code into the GetCourseByCourseID method which is where I get stuck.

```
class CourseList
{
    public Course[] CourseArray = 
        { 
        new Course ("CIS 400", "OO Analysis & Design", 4, "Important class", "CIS 110") ,
        new Course ("CIS 150A" , "VB.NET Programming", 4, "Good Introduction to programming", "CIS 100") ,
        new Course ("CIS 150B", "C# Programming with labs", 4, "Follow-up to CIS 100", "CIS 100")
        };


    public Course GetCourseByCourseID(string id)
    {

    }

}
```

Since "CIS 101" is not a course in the CourseList we have to return null. The whole point of the exercise is to get the console to display nothing. That means the code is working properly.

I don't want the answer. I was just wanted an example of how to get this to work. Being that the code was already given to us.

Comment: You clearly have to add the code that searches the CourseArray to see if CIS 101 is in there, and return the proper value if it is not. So start with searching the array. (You'll need a for loop.)

Comment: Without knowing what you've tried, we have no idea what you already know. Do you know how to write a loop? How to access an array?

Comment: As well as marking RadioSpace's answer, as the answer, also vote it up. He would like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'll keep this close to c++ syntax.

there are many other ways but...

```
public Course GetCourseByCourseID(string id)
{
     for(int x = 0; x < CourseArray.Length; x++)
     {
          if(CourseArray[x].CourseID == id) {return CourseArray[x];}
     }       

     return null;
}
```

your array is static you could just use `x < 3`

and for a more c# way

```
using System.Linq;


public Course GetCourseByCourseID(string id)
{
     return CourseArray.Where(a => a.CourseID == id).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

a is each course and First return the first element in the resulting collection. a pit fall with this approach is that if you have more than one Course with the same id you only get the first one.
but then that is likely a design flaw.

it should be noted that if `CourseArray` were to be multidimensional. then length would not be usable because it return the total number of elements in all dimensions of the array. thus using System.Linq Count() extension method would have to be used.

Comment: Arrays do have a way to get their item count, `.Length`

Comment: @Spans DOH!! funny how simple things can slip the mind

Comment: Your first example would not compile and your second example can throw exceptions under normal situations.

Comment: @OmegaMan Handling Exceptions are up to the op. but what error came up for the first?

Comment: @OmegaMan thanks for not down voting and the heads up. I have been DV'd for less.

Comment: @RadioSpace The competition on SO can bring out the worst in people. The end goal is to help someone and there can be other answers; the other people seem to forget that in the holy grail of getting recognition points. IMHO :-)

Comment: @RadioSpace Change the linq example to `FirstOrDefault()` and it answers his question without throwing an exception.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to use a `foreach` loop, checking through all the courses until the ID matches. If no ID matches, the loop will exit and you should return null.

The more 'advanced' way would be to use LINQ, either straight up LINQ or the extension methods to achieve the same result but with less code.

Answer (score 0):

With any language it is best to state a return variable which will start in a failure state. Then do the work of trying to find the non failure state and assign it to the return variable. If one doesn't find a non failure state, no assignment is done and the return value is correct as null.

Example:

```
public Course GetCourseByCourseID(string id)
{
    Course foundCourse = null;

    if (CourseArray != null)
    {
       // Check course array here for the id and if one is found, assign to foundCourse.   
    }

    return foundCourse;

}
```

So within the if's you can continue to remove any possible failure situations. The one above in the `if` checks CourseArray for null. If it is null it gracefully exits and doesn't throw an exception about trying to check CourseArray. Keep doing 'sanity' checks where possible and it makes for better programming.

Comment: Wow thanks guys for such fast responses. I would have posted what I have tried, but all I kept getting were NullRederenceException errors and StackOverFlow errors. I just completely didn't know how to tackle it. C#'s syntax seems a bit tricky but not to far off from C++. I think it is just me still learning the lay of the land maybe. Thanks again for the help! I think I will read up on more C#.